# Define logarithmic power for NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, logarithm

I am trying to define ln<sup>2</sup>(x/y) in Python, within NumPy.

I can define ln(x) as `np.log(x)` but how I can define ln<sup>2</sup>(x/y)?

ln<sup>2</sup>(x/y); natural logarithm to the power of 2

Comment: By saying `ln^2(x)` is "natural logarithm to the power of 2", do you mean `(ln(x))^2`, or `ln_2(x)`?

Comment: @Eric Isn't that pretty clear? I suppose _natural logarithm of x to the power of 2_ would be a bit more precise.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm forgetting that the correct word to use for the subscript version is base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches you can take, depending on how general you'd like your formula to be.

```
In[107]: np.allclose(np.log(4/3)*np.log(4/3), 
                     np.power(np.log(4/3), 2), 
                     np.log(4/3)**2)
Out[107]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a Math notation, no special meaning.

```
ln^2(x/y)
```

is the same as:

```
ln(x/y) * ln(x/y)
```

You can use the above or alternatively use [`np.power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) to raise `ln(x/y)` to the power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `**` for exponentiation: `np.log(x/y) ** 2`